# Defined public properties on a struct can not be accessed implementing interface

Tags: go

There is an interface Comment that has to be implemented in order to be accessible by a package functionality. Though implementing the interface and then making a slice of CommentTest objects but with Comment as items type makes the Title public property undefined. PS: Stringer works fine in this case. Is there a way to make it work without type assertion?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Comment interface {
    SetChild(Comment)
    GetChildren() []Comment
    GetID() int
    GetParentID() int
}

type CommentTest struct {
    Title string
    ID int
    ParentID int
    Children []Comment
}

func (ct *CommentTest) SetChild(c Comment) {
    ct.Children = append(ct.Children, c)
}

func (ct CommentTest) GetChildren() []Comment {
    return ct.Children
}

func (ct CommentTest) GetID() int {
    return ct.ID
}

func (ct CommentTest) GetParentID() int {
    return ct.ParentID
}
// works well, all public properties are 100% accesible
func (ct CommentTest) String() string {
    return "{ID: " + strconv.Itoa(ct.ID) + ", ParentID: " + strconv.Itoa(ct.ParentID) + ", Title: " + ct.Title + "}"
}

/*
    There are test comments with this structure:

        1 ->
            2 ->
                4
            3 ->
                5
 */
func testData() (Comment, []Comment) {
    var plain []Comment

    root := &CommentTest{ID: 1, ParentID: 3, Title: "Test 1"} // ParentID 3 -> Check for infinite recursion

    plain = append(plain, root)
    plain = append(plain, &CommentTest{ID: 2, ParentID: 1, Title: "Test 2"})
    plain = append(plain, &CommentTest{ID: 3, ParentID: 1, Title: "Test 3"})
    plain = append(plain, &CommentTest{ID: 4, ParentID: 2, Title: "Test 4"})
    plain = append(plain, &CommentTest{ID: 5, ParentID: 3, Title: "Test 5"})

    return root, plain
}

func main() {
    root, plain := testData()

    fmt.Println(root) // works well

    root.Title //root.Title undefined (type Comment has no field or method Title)

}
```

Comment: If you need access to the fields, you shouldn't be using an interface. Interfaces describe *behavior*, not *data*. This appears to be a flawed design in your code - either you don't need the interface, or you're using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `root` is of type `Comment`, which is an interface, thus, it is a set of methods. It does not have any member variables.

There are several things you can do:

- Use type assertion, as you mentioned.
- Add a GetTitle() method to CommentTest, and use a separate interface:

```
type titler interface { GetTitle() string }
if t, ok:=root.(titler); ok {
    t.GetTitle()
}
```

Comment: Well, the struct CommentTest will be defined outside of the package, so it wouldn't be possible to add such interface. The type assertion looks not optimized and clunky, maybe I'm mistaken though.

Comment: You don't need the interface in the same package as CommentTest. If CommentTest has a GetTitle method, you can define the interface inline where you need it.

Comment: The titler interface does not really solves the problem, still have to check type. I guess that the type assertion to check if it CommentTest can not be avoided in this case

Comment: If all you need is Title, then the interface gives you that. If you need more, you can use type assertion, or add those to the `titler` interface. Type assertion is not clunky though

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces only provide access to *methods*, not fields (they're agnostic to the field layout of whatever hides behind them, or whether it's even a struct). You can add a `GetTitle()` method to the interface, and use that.

Comment: Well, it would make my interface even more uglier than it is now, 4 methods is a lot already.